# Visual studio comment out partial line differences between 2010-2012

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I am not sure this is SO or programmers question, If not let me know / remove this.

In VS 2010 when commented-out partial row, it would comment with /**/ the select string.
In VS 2012 when commented-out partial row, it would comment-out the entire row.

If I'd want to comment-out the entire row - i would comment out the entire row and would not select part of it.

Is it fixable ?

This is the commenting:

[image]

VS 2012 behavior (the annoying behavior):
[image]

VS 2010 behavior - the one i want to keep..

[image]

Comment: There might be a setting to change in [PPT2012](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/3a96a4dc-ba9c-4589-92c5-640e07332afd).

Comment: This is almost certainly not intentional.  You can report the bug at connect.microsoft.com